# Newton's Generalization of the Binomial Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **(Newton's Generalization of the Binomial Theorem)**
>
> Let $x,y∈\mathbb{R}$ where $0≤∣x∣<∣y∣$ and let $α∈\mathbb{R}$. Then the expansion of the binomial $(x+y)^α$ is given by the infinite series
>
> $$(x+y)^α=\binom{\alpha}{0}x^0y^α+\binom{\alpha}{1}x^1y^{\alpha -1}+\binom{\alpha}{2}x^αy^{2−α}+...=∑_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^ky^{α−k}$$

---

Now why  :

$$(1+z)^{\frac{1}{n}}\sim 1+\frac{1}{n}z+O(z^2)$$

Comment: In your series, what is $n$?  Did you mean to type $\alpha$ instead?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but still, what is $n$ in the middle series?

Comment: @kimchilover .ohhhhhhh im sorry $n=\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=1$ and $x=z$, then the formula is $(1+z)^\alpha=\sum_{k\ge0}\binom\alpha k z^k$ and the result is that the series converges for $|z|<1$.  This means that the left-hand side minus the first two terms is $$(1+z)^\alpha-(1+\alpha z) = z^2 \sum_{k\ge2}\binom\alpha k z^{k-2},$$ where again the series converges for $|z|<1$.  This implies the desired result: $z^2 \sum_{k\ge2}\binom\alpha k z^{k-2}=O(z^2)$, so $$(1+z)^\alpha-(1+\alpha z) =O(z^2)$$ and
$$(1+z)^\alpha =1+\alpha z +O(z^2).$$  Take $\alpha=1/n$ and you get $$(1+z)^{1/n} =1+ z/n +O(z^2).$$

The only tricky thing here is not to be distracted by thinking that $n$ is large or $1/n$ is small.  The small thing in this question is $z$, as hinted by the $O(z^2)$ notation.

Answer (score 0):

This you wrote is not Newtons generalization of the binomial theorem. See here:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/General_Binomial_Theorem

Comment: see :http://mathonline.wikidot.com/newton-s-generalization-of-the-binomial-theorem

Comment: Power of $x$ should be $2$ not $α$ in the first equality.